# "X came with a Y included" vs "Y came included with a X"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

> His iPhone came with a phone case included.
>
> His iPhone came included with a phone case.

Do these sentences have the same meaning? Is one more idiomatic or common than the other?

Comment: I've heard of conditional love, but with a phone case? Assuming that *love* is the result of some strange autocorrection of *iPhone*, they mean the same thing. It's hard to check, but I'd say the first is more common.

Comment: “Included with a phone case” connotes it was the phone case that was purchased and the iphone was graciously thrown in.

Comment: @deadrat A typo. A typo!

Comment: @Jim True, but isn't that the way things are going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> His iPhone came with a phone case included.

This means that when he bought the iPhone, a phone case was included in the package, with ostensibly no extra cost.  The case was thrown in as a marketing extra.